# Why can't I use array initialisation syntax separate from array declaration?

Tags: c#, arrays

I can do this with an integer:

```
int a;
a = 5;
```

But I can't do this with an integer array:

```
int[] a;
a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Why not?

To clarify, **I am not looking for the correct syntax (I can look that up)**; I know that this works:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
int a = 5;
```

What I am trying to understand is, why does the code fail for arrays? What is the reason behind the code failing to be recognised as valid?

Comment: this can be made possible. you just have to give your idea here. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015 it may be accepted or not depending on votes and the the amount of work and time developers have to put for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason there is a difference is that the folks at Microsoft decided to lighten the syntax when *declaring **and** initializing* the array in the same statement, but did not add the required syntax to allow you to assign a new array to it later.

This is why this works:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

but this does not:

```
int[] a;
a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Could they have added the syntax to allow this? Sure, but they didn't. Most likely they felt that this use-case is so seldom used that it didn't warrant prioritizing over other features. [All new features start with minus 100 points](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) and this probably just didn't rank high enough on the priority list.

Note that `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` by itself has no meaning; it can only appear in two places:

- As part of an array variable declaration:

  ```
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  ```
- As part of an array creation expression:

  ```
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
  ```

The number `5`, on the other hand, has a meaning everywhere it appears in C#, which is why this works:

```
int a;
a = 5;
```

So this is just special syntax the designers of C# decided to support, nothing more.

This syntax is documented in the C# specification, section [12.6 Array Initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: I could easily see the reason why it only works in that single instance be the fact that anywhere else, it could be confusing to see. Only when you explicitly type your variable, and declare it right there is it completely clear what is happening.

Comment: A reason for disallowing such syntax is that it's not clear whether `int[] arr; for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { arr = {1,2,3,4,5}; foo(arr); }` is *intended* to create a new array each time through the loop, or is intended to create one array that is used for every loop iteration.  If code does `arr = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};` then it's clear that each pass through the loop is intended to create a new object; any legal syntax for creating the array just once will require that its creation be pulled out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your array example doesn't work is because of the difference between [value and reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx). An `int` is a value type. It is a single location in memory whose value can be changed.

Your integer array is a reference type. It is not equivalent to a constant number of bytes in memory. Therefore, it is a pointer to the bytes where that data is stored.

In this first line, you are assigning `null` to `a`.

```
int[] a;
```

In the next line, if you want to change the value of the array, you need to assign it to a new array.

```
a = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

That is why you need the `new[]` before the list of values within the array if you strongly type your declaration.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // This will work.
var a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // This will not.
```

However, as many of the other answers have said, if you declare it in a single line, then you do not need the `new[]`. If you separate the declaration and initialization, then you are required to use `new[]`.

Comment: untrue. this is just a syntactic sugar when declaring and initializing variable in one line. you can do it all without `new` . you can do this `int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`. and this doesnt mean you are not creating new array. you cant just do it in two lines. the reason is obvious. compiler doesnt like it.

Comment: If it is so obvious, then tell me why the compiler doesn't like it. I have updated my answer for very clear reasons when and why each are required, and when some will not work.

Comment: i cant think of anything that conflicts with this syntax. maybe there are another reasons. but its all about syntaxes. nothing else.

Answer (score -1):

`{}`  syntax is available for array initialization, not to be used after declaration.

Answer (score -3):

To initialize an array you should try like this:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Other ways to Initializing a Single-dimensional array:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] a = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Have a look at this:  [different ways to initialize different kinds of arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: This does not address the question OP asked; they asked why it does not work, not how to do it.