# C# Array declaration with commas

Tags: c#, arrays

Why can't I just re-declare an array with commas?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    short[] arr = new short[6] { 1,1,1,1,1,1 };

    if(1)
    {
        arr = {1,0,0,1,1,0}; // this line doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: short[] arr = { 1,1,1,1,1,1 };

Comment: `if(1)`, what is this javascript?

Comment: `var bool = true; if(bool) { DoTheThing() };` is legit.  I use if(bool) all the time ._.

Comment: @Kyle that's fine, but `if(1)` will not compile in C#, and its much different from `if(someBoolVar)` [See for yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZsFJR)

Comment: Sorry, my noobies C-remindings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I use array initialisation syntax separate from array declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983810/why-cant-i-use-array-initialisation-syntax-separate-from-array-declaration)

Comment: wtf, I did not vote to close it as "primarily opinion based", I voted to close it as duplicate of the question suggested by Horton.

Answer (score 7):

The initialization expression is not `{1,0,0,1,1,0}`

The initialization expression must be `new short[6] { 1,1,1,1,1,1 }`

So, essentially, the statement of your question is the answer to your question.

Comment: You could omit the length specifier though.

Comment: @ckuri yes, that's right, and preferable.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax : `short[] arr = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};`
 is called array initialization syntax and it works only in ***declaration***.
why ?

As the guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983810/why-cant-i-use-array-initialisation-syntax-separate-from-array-declaration) wrote, it just how Microsoft guys choose to implement for some reason.